# How reinstall the /bin/echo in my debian?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, echo

Something wrong for my `/bin/echo` command.

```
sudo ls -al  /bin/echo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root utmp 0 Nov 11 18:05 /bin/echo
```

method1 to fix it:
I knew that `/bin/echo` is in `coretils`.
Remove coreutils first then reinstall it again.

```
sudo apt-get remove coreutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
```

I can't remove it ,it is no use to remove it and reinstall coreutils?

method2 to fix it:
compile the echo.c.

```
cd  /tmp
sudo apt-get source coreutils
cd  coreutils-8.26
/tmp/coreutils-8.26$ ./configure
./configure: line 3492: config.log: Permission denied
./configure: line 3502: config.log: Permission denied
```

Let me config it with `sudo`.

```
sudo ./configure
configure: error: you should not run configure as root (set FORCE_UNSAFE_CONFIGURE=1 in environment to bypass this check)
```

How to fix the `/bin/echo` in my debian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a proper `.deb` file:

```
mkdir ~/dummy
cd ~/dummy
apt-get download coreutils
```

Unpack it:

```
sudo dpkg-deb -x *.deb ./
```

(Note: `dpkg-deb` can run without `sudo` but it's easier to unpack as root to obtain the `echo` file with proper ownership from the beginning).

The executable you seek is `./bin/echo`. Replace `/bin/echo`:

```
sudo mv ./bin/echo /bin/
```

Remove the directory:

```
cd ~/
sudo rm -rf ~/dummy
```

Comment: That's an odd solution. I'd say a mere `# apt install --reinstall coreutils` should have worked, no?

Comment: @kostix Write an answer and I will upvote it. My answer touches `/bin/echo` only; the other extremity is to reinstall the entire OS. Your way is somewhere in between.